# Check if remote file is well-formed XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, feed

I have a PHP-driven site that includes an XML stock feed, which is remotely served from ASP (i.e. the XML feed url is of the order: http://remote.com/client.asp).

As the feed is often unavailable (by which I mean the site returns an ASP error) I'd like to check if the feed is well-formed XML before including it. My usual url_exists function doesn't do the trick as of course the URL does exist even when 'erroring'.

TIA.

Comment: Note: be careful with terminology.  What you're describing sounds like "well-formed" XML, which means something different to "valid" XML.

Comment: Quite right cletus (thanks) editing now...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) to get the result and [simplexml](https://www.php.net/simplexml) to check if the XML is [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formed_and_Valid_XML_documents).

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://remote.com/client.asp");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if (simplexml_load_string($output)) {
  // well-formed XML
} else {
  // it isn't
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using something very similar to that, and it is this script that often throws an error. Though I'm using simplexml_load_file, would there be a difference with simplexml_load_string?

Comment: I'm having problem with SimpleXML and it's very weird. Apparently simplexml_load_file() from URL and simplexml_load_string() from cURL result of URL could get different result. One could fail while another could work...It's beyond me how that happened. Taking a look at my cURL function now

Comment: simplexml_load_string throws warnings when going through a html... it is not failing where it should