# Check for a valid XML file PHP

Tags: php, xml, validation

With curl I dowload XML file and saved localy. How can I check this file is valid XML.
After donloadedd I save to mysql information from this file.

```
    $url = '<URL to XML>';
    $local_path = "myxml.xml";
    $file_handle = fopen($local_path, "w");

    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handle);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // times out after 4s
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    fclose($file_handle);
```

I tried this but not working.

```
if (filesize('myxml.xml')>0) {

    $str_xml = file_get_contents('myxml.xml');
    if(simplexml_load_string($str_xml)){
        echo 'XML';
    }else{
        echo 'NOT XML';
    }
```

Code returned this WRONG

**Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in**

Where I wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please edit your question and clarify. Also: please accept answers to your questions!

Comment: simple: when `simplexml_load_file` gives you errors, the file is invalid.

Comment: Also, consider using simplexml_load_file() instead of simplexml_load_string()

Comment: Echo the XML and see the structure. Does it starts with empty space?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441044/check-if-remote-file-is-well-formed-xml-with-php and this - http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.isvalid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the parsing of the XML that is wrong.

You are getting a misformed XML from the CURL retrieval. Do a echo of the `$str_xml` and see whats wrong with it!

Comment: There are cases that do not return a valid XML. I just want to check whether the downloaded file is XML or not